# Get first table count which has been unioned into multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

Here is a pseudo code what I want.
I need to get count of fist union in following statement.

```
SELECT *  
FROM Table1 
UNION 
SELECT Cats.Id + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Fist_Union_Result), 
       Cats.Name 
FROM Table2
```

Any idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ADO.NET EntityDataSource Error >> The right expression must be of numeric or string type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108810/ado-net-entitydatasource-error-the-right-expression-must-be-of-numeric-or-str)

Comment: COUNT(*) only from the first select statement or both?

Comment: Describe some example data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the first part is a complex query, you could use the `with` clause to alias it.  That allows you to use it in two places, the top part of the union and the place where you count:

```
; with  FirstPart as
        (
        select  *
        from    Table1
        )
select  *
from    FirstPart
union all
select  cats.Id - cnt.cnt
,       cats.Name
from    Table2 cats
cross join
        (
        select  count(*) as cnt
        from    FistPart
        ) as cnt
```

If you just want a unique ID, you could place the `union` in a subquery and just label the rows 1..N:

```
select  row_number() over (order by Name) as Id
,       Name
from    (
        select  Name
        from    Table1
        union all
        select  Name
        from    Table2
        ) as SubQueryAlias
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
with first_union_result as (
  select col1, 
         col2
  from table1
), count_from_first as (
  select count(*) as first_count
  from first_union_result
)
select col1, 
       col2
from first_union_result
union all
select cats.id + cnt.first_count,
       cats.name
from cats
  cross join count_from_first as cnt;
```

If you are trying to get some unique id or something similar into the overall result, you might be better off using `row_number()` to generate that for all rows.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Andomar answer solved my problem.